# React native position absolute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

I've stuck on one issue with development react native app for android phone.  I don't know why but a setting position with the absolute option doesn't work on Android and works on IOS. I need your help guys!

Stackoverflow asks me to add more details but I don't know what details should here else - that's why this is the useless sentence here :).

```
<ScrollView>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{width: '97%'}}>
      <FormLabel>Ship title</FormLabel>
      <FormInput containerStyle={styles.inputShipTitle}/>
      <Card title='Pickup Address' titleNumberOfLines={1} dividerStyle={{width: 0}}>
        <View>
          <Icon
            iconStyle={styles.iconPickup}
            name='map-marker' type='font-awesome'
            size={normalize(25)}
          />
          <Text style={styles.additionalText}>Tap to select the pickup address</Text>
        </View>
      </Card>
      <Card title='Delivery Address' titleNumberOfLines={1} dividerStyle={{width: 0}}>
        <View>
          <Icon
            iconStyle={styles.iconTruck}
            name='truck' type='font-awesome'
            size={normalize(23)}
          />
          <Text style={styles.additionalText}>Tap to select the delivery address</Text>
        </View>
      </Card>
      <Card title='Pickup date' titleNumberOfLines={1} dividerStyle={{width: 0}}>
        <View>
          <Icon
            iconStyle={styles.icon}
            name='calendar' type='font-awesome'
            size={normalize(23)}
          />
          <Text style={styles.additionalText}>Tap to select the pickup date</Text>
        </View>
      </Card>
      <Card title='Pickup time' titleNumberOfLines={1} dividerStyle={{width: 0}}>
        <View>
          <Icon
            iconStyle={styles.icon}
            name='clock-o' type='font-awesome'
            size={normalize(23)}
          />
          <Text style={styles.additionalText}>Tap to select the pickup time</Text>
        </View>
      </Card>
      <Card title='Add Photo or Video'
            titleNumberOfLines={1}
            dividerStyle={{width: 0}}>
        <View>
          <Icon
            iconStyle={styles.iconPhoto}
            name='camera' type='font-awesome'
            size={normalize(23)}
          />
        </View>
      </Card>
    </View>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

And styles :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
},
inputShipTitle: {
    height: verticalScale(45),
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderRadius: 3,
},
icon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: moderateScale(5),
    bottom: moderateScale(5),
},
iconPhoto: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: moderateScale(5),
    bottom: moderateScale(5),
},
iconPickup: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: moderateScale(8),
    bottom: moderateScale(5),
    zIndex:1,
},
iconTruck: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: moderateScale(5),
    bottom: moderateScale(5),
    // right: width * 0.03,
},
additionalText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: moderateScale(10),
    left: moderateScale(60,2),
    fontSize: normalize(7),
    color: 'grey',
}
});
```

The 1st picture is IOS and the 2nd one is android.

[image: IOS]

[image: Android]

Comment: Does this work in Android when you remove the `position:absolute` style property?

Comment: try adding a `position: relative` to your container view style

Comment: @GirishSortur yes. it works if position absolute is removed. But icons located on the center of the screen accordance with container style .

Comment: @IsaacSekamatte unfortunately, adding position: relative didn't help .